401 Unauthorized while writing file into Google storage using flink
I am using flink to perform some data transformation and I am using Google cloud storage as the filesystem, as stated in the resource here I am setting the property google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile for authentication. With this process I am able to read the file and process it but at the time of writing back the file into Google cloud storage I am facing unauthorized error from google storage as shown below
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/test-bucket-120710242024/o?name=.inprogress/test-bucket-120710242024/ca9b2014-2b70-45ab-8711-ecca9d079077/2024-10-24-08/refine-e2a9bf5b-294f-4bde-8489-00b9e3fb7954-0.csv/8b60bbce-8937-439e-92f9-9082ea461cc5&uploadType=resumable
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException$Builder.build(HttpResponseException.java:293)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1118)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.open(HttpStorageRpc.java:1037)
    ... 57 more


How are you deploying this job? Do you have an example of what the configuration looks like? These can be tricky to ensure you have the appropriate plugins for communicating with GCS as well as the proper credentials mounted, etc.
